# How to apply ascending ID parameter to thousands of multiple module types

Tags: omnet++

Suppose I have a simple module `Client` defined in `Client.ned` along with two subclassed simple modules:

```
simple Client
{
    parameters:
        volatile int clientId;
}

simple ClientA extends Client
{
}

simple ClientB extends Client
{
}
```

Now what I wish to do is define a network `Network` with 1000 `ClientA` instances and 1000 `Client 2` instances as its submodules. I would like each instantiation to have a `clientId` one bigger than the last, i.e I would like the `clientId` parameter to ascend with each instantiation. For example, suppose we have the following `Network.ned` file:

```
network Network
{
    submodules:
        clientA[1000]: ClientA {
            clientId = index;
        };
        clientB[1000]: ClientB {
            clientId = 1000 + index;
        } 
}
```

What I'm looking for is a general approach, where we don't know the number of clients that are to be instantiated beforehand or even the number of client subclasses, just that if there is an instantiated `Client` of some sort, it should have a `clientId` parameter one larger than the last instantiation.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `volatile` from `clientId` declaration in `Client.ned` and your solution will work properly.
The main purpose of using `volatile` is to guarantee returning a "fresh" value of a parameter when it is reading several times. In your network the `clientId` is constant, so the `volatile` is not necessary. The side-effect of using `volatile` is problem with using `index`, and `parentIndex`.

Beside the above, one should be aware that using `omnetpp.ini` is a very convenient method of control the simulation. For example, your NED files may look like:

```
simple Client {
  parameters:
     int clientId;
}

simple ClientA extends Client { }

simple ClientB extends Client { } 

network Network {
  submodules:
     clientA[1000]: ClientA;
     clientB[1000]: ClientB;
}
```

And the parameters may be set in `omnetpp.ini`:

```
**.clientA[*].clientId = index() 
**.clientB[*].clientId = 1000 + index()
```

**EDIT**

When the number of clients is not known [sizeof()](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:ned-ref:sizeof-operator) method may be used to determine this number:

```
**.clientA[*].clientId = index() 
**.clientB[*].clientId = sizeof(clientA) + index()
```

Comment: I understand now there is no need for `volatile,` but I'm looking for a more general approach to assigning `clientId`s. Suppose I don't know there will be 1000 `ClientA` instances so I don't know the offset to include when assigning the `clientId`s for `ClientB` instances.

Comment: I have edited my answer and included an additional clue.

Comment: Right, I'm familiar with `sizeof()`. I suppose this will be the closest I get to what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Since OMNeT++'s simulator assigns an ascending ID's to every module and submodule, utilizing `getId()`, `getIndex()`, `getVectorSize()`, and `getParentModule()` allows me to access this info for each module.